# I can't find my jar file when trying to copy it in a multi stage docker build

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, gradle, dockerfile

So I am very new to docker and I have been trying to dockerise my spring-boot application. I managed to get it working with a given JAR file but now I would like to make a multi stage build to build the JAR file using gradle so that I don't have to manually generate the JAR before running `docker build {app-name}`

This is my current setup. It fails to find the jar file and I don't know how I can navigate the filesystem to find it (other than running shell commands in the dockerfile to print out the files & folders)

[DOCKERFILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1aJz.png)

```
FROM gradle:jdk8 as build

COPY --chown:gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src

WROKDIR /home/gradle/src 

RUN gradle clean build --parallel

FROM  openjdk:8-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY --from=build /home/gradle/src/app-name.jar /usr/app/

RUN sh -c 'touch app-name.jar'

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app-name.jar"]
```

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSO4T.png)

```
Step 7/9. : COPY —from=build /home/gradle/src/app-name.jar /usr/app/
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/ldocker/overlay2/22e326d9f26f581a629417c35e226428f3cc63fd496799c55dde4be413ca26690/merged/home/gradle/src/app-name.jar: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Why can't you do what you suggested and run e.g. `find` in the Dockerfile to determine the name and path of the JAR file that gradle built?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Prevent using images when possible, add you setup as text and try to create a minimal example. For more details have a look at [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: @hmm I actually didn't think to use the find command. Embarrassingly I was just running commands like `cd lib | ls`. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @JeroenHeier thanks for the link, I have never posted on here before. Will give it a read!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `COPY` directive needs to copy from gradle's `build/libs/` directory which is the default location for build artifacts - as it stands it's looking for the JAR in the project root. This should work:

`COPY —from=build /home/gradle/src/build/libs/app-name.jar /usr/app`

This assumes the Dockerfile is located in your project's root directory.  If it's not, then you'll need to adjust the copy path used in the dockerfile accordingly.

Comment: I had a different issue but through this answer figured out that `build/libs/` would not find the jar file in the second stage, better to specify the absolute path.
Thanks for the answer